# Silverlight Toolkit Complex Column and StackedColumn Chart

Tags: silverlight-5.0, charts

Can it be done?

I would like to have a standard column chart with three series, one of these series to be made up of two as a stacked column like so:

[image: Stacked column with normal column on same chart]

I have attempted to implement it but I ended up with something very odd. The interpretation was interesting though.

I am almost certain the answer is no but if anyone out there knows how I could do it, that would be grand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is to use the standard Silverlight StackedColumnSeries with the following dataset:

```
          Bottom       Top

Red       ##           0

Orange    ##           ##

Green     ##           0
```

This achieves the desired effect.